# PUT call to RESTapi giving error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express, rest

I'm working with React, Typescript and a self-made RESTapi.

I'm trying to make a PUT request to my api from my client in React, but i keep on getting the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0". The PUT call to the api contains no body, nor should it due to the way I created the request in my API. I have confirmed that the url in fetch is the correct one, and that the API call works perfectly fine when testing it directly in my API. Therefore the problem seems to be something with the way i make the PUT call in the client

Below is my PUT call from my client.

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
  function putProductInBasket(id: number){
      
      fetch("http://localhost:3005/velocishop/customers/" + localStorage.uuid + "/baskets/" + localStorage.uuid + "/products/" +  id, { 
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
      })
        .then(response => {
          if (response.ok)
            return Promise.resolve ({ status:response.statusText}) 
          else
            return Promise.reject ({ status:response.statusText})
        }
        )
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first convert the response from fetch into json by using `res.json()`
Something like this

```
fetch('/data.json')
  .then(response => response.json()) // Add this .then block before your first .then block
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(err => ...)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately this did not solve the issue - I now get both "SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0" and "SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0" errors, and the request is still 400 Bad request. Do you by any chance have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: I can see that you have "Content-Type": "application/json" and no body in req. You can remove that header. res.json() might still be required to process your response correctly. However, you can first try by removing that header.

Comment: I removed it now, and tried both with res.json() and without. With res.json() I still get the same 2 errors, without res.json() I get the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0"

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `Content-Type: application/json` body, not sending a body is invalid because the expectation is that you actually send JSON.

Removing this header might fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried removing it from the header, however, I still get the error. Do you by any chance know how to fix that?

Comment: @ssh if you removed the header, there is basically no JSON involved anymore. Where are you calling `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed in an error from another call. I do not get the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0" anymore, however, my PUT request still returns 400 Bad request and is not working for some reason

Comment: @ssh that's a server-side issue then

Comment: yes, thank you! It was indeed a server issue. I used parseInt() a place where i shouldn't on my server :)